# How does named pipe in Linux works?

Tags: linux, ipc

I'm trying to use named pipe in Linux, using mkfifo.
Below are codes for sender / reader of named pipe :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MSG_SIZE 100
//SENDER
int main() {
    
    char msg[MSG_SIZE] = "FIFO is for first-in, first-out.";
    int fd;
    int cnt;

    if(fd = open("./hello", O_RDWR) < 0) {  //fifo acts as a typical file
        perror("Failed to make fifo : ");
        printf("Error : %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int len = strlen(msg) + 1;

    while(1) {
        if(write(fd, msg, len) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to write into fifo : ");
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            printf("Succeed to write msg!");
            break;
        }
    }

    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}


#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MSG_SIZE 100
//READER
int main() {

    char msg_rc[MSG_SIZE];

    int fd;

    if(access("./hello",F_OK) == 0) {
        fd = open("./hello", O_RDWR);
        if(fd < 0) {
            perror("Failed to open fifo : ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(fd = mkfifo("./hello", O_RDWR) < 0) {
            perror("Failed to open fifo : ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    printf("Waiting for fifo update");
    while(1) {
        if(read(fd, msg_rc, MSG_SIZE) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to read from fifo : ");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Read msg : %s\n", msg_rc);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I used these codes,

% ./fifoSender
FIFO is for first-in, first-out.Succeed to write msg!%

% ./fifoReader

fifoSender shows msg, and fifoReader shows no msg, which are not desirable behavior.

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: `if(access("./hello",F_OK) == 0) {` is almost always an error,google TOCTOU.

Comment: `if(fd = open("./hello", O_RDWR) < 0)` [Read this now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: Changed the title, thx for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is these two lines

```
if(fd = open("./hello", O_RDWR) < 0) {
if(fd = mkfifo("./hello", O_RDWR) < 0) {
```

They don't do what you think they do.

Firstly, `O_RDWR` is a wrong argument for `mkfifo`. It expects Unix file permissions mask, such as `S_IRWU"S_IRWG|S_IRWO`, or just `0666`.

Secondly and most importantly, since the priority of `=` is lower than that of `<`, they are parsed like this:

```
if(fd = (open("./hello", O_RDWR) < 0)) {
```

Now, when `open("./hello", O_RDWR)` is less than 0 (which is highly likely, given that it is either never created or created with an incorrect `mode`), `fd` becomes 1, which is the standard output file descriptor.

The correct incantation is

```
if((fd = open("./hello", O_RDWR)) < 0) { // note () around assignment
if((fd = mkfifo("./hello", 0666)) < 0) {
```

There are several more subtle shortcomings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code,

```c
// sender 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PIPE_NAME "./hello"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *message = "FIFO is for first-in, first-out\n";
    // Open the pipe for writing
    int pipe_fd = open(PIPE_NAME, O_WRONLY);
    if (pipe_fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Write data to the pipe
    while(1){
        int n = write(pipe_fd, message, strlen(message));
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    // Close the pipe
    close(pipe_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

```c
//receiver
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PIPE_NAME "./hello"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create the named pipe
    mknod(PIPE_NAME, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    // Open the pipe for reading
    int pipe_fd = open(PIPE_NAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (pipe_fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read data from the pipe
    char buffer[1024];
    while(1){
        
        int n = read(pipe_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        // Print the data that was read
        printf("Received: %.*s\n", n, buffer);
    }
    // Close the pipe
    close(pipe_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.